# "Hello World" fails to run. Eclipse (Galileo) CDT plugin problems with MinGW and Cygwin on Windows Vista

Tags: c++, windows-vista, cygwin, mingw, eclipse-cdt

Trying to run a simple Hello World C++ program on Eclipse (Galileo) CDT plugin on Windows Vista. Following the "Before You Begin" instructions for Eclipse/CDT...

1) Downloaded and installed the latest Cygwin. However, could not compile with Cygwin.

> Internal Builder: Cannot run program "g++": Launching failed

the Eclipse CDT docs say...

> currently Cygwin >= version 3.4.4-999 is not supported since gcc and g++ commands cannot >be launched from the windows' native shell

It seems to be a typo (Cygwin version is at 1.7.7) but running cygcheck -c, I get the version of g++ which is 3.4.4.x.
Hence I assumed that this version of g++ cannot be run from the command line. So gave up on Cygwin.

2)  Downloaded and installed MinGW, gdb, MSYS.
This time, it was able to compile, but when trying to run, I get a popup saying that

> the program Hello.exe has stopped working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution was to install the latest Eclipse (Helios SR1) and the CDT plugin.
I needed to also delete the old projects/import old source into new projects.

For Galileo, see:
http://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2010-03/msg00510.html
http://dreamlayers.blogspot.com/2010/01/eclipse-incompatibility-with-cygwin-17.html

Answer (score 4):

You should use either Cygwin, or Mingw, because their dll's might conflict if they're both discoverable via %PATH%.
Show your build process (copypaste text from your build console) and %PATH% contents.